# How do I fix Cannot read property 'style' of null in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

So my function Updates the progress bar based on the document.load set value. From What I can see, its not able to render that element. After extensive research I am not sure why my other divs can be recognised and manipulated in JS but not this specific element;

```
<div id="ProgressBar">
     <div id="Percentage" class="innerBar" runat="server"></div>
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        SpaceLeftVar = 32;
        UpdateProgress();
    });

function UpdateProgress() {

    const progressBarPercentage = document.getElementById('Percentage');

    const transitionProgressBar = (progress) => {

        setTimeout(() => {
            progressBarPercentage.style.width = progress + '%';
         }, 200);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). The above is at best incomplete (nothing ever calls `transitionProgressBar`) and in the above, I can't see any reason why `progressBarPercentage` would be `null` unless the code in the question is not an accurate example of your real code.

Comment: Also: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score -1):

```
setTimeout(() => { 
    progressBarPercentage && (progressBarPercentage.style.width = progress + '%')
}, 200);
```

Comment: You should include some narrative in your answer and not just a code snippet.

Comment: Hah, yeah! Totally. I was on my mobile and about to get off the train, so I had to cut it short unfortunately.